# Globals once again

Tags: c++

I know that nearly everything has been said on 'globals' topic. Apologies for coming back to it here. There is something in the production code, I don't fully understand. Would very much appreciate help on that. so thanks in advance.

Consider following implementation:

file1.h

```
class classA
{
    classA();
    // something in 
};

const classA& GetClassA();
```

file1.cpp

```
classA::ClassA()
{

    cout << "I have been called";

    // do initialization
}


const classA obA;

const classA& GetClassA() { return obA; }
```

The GetClassA function is called all around. The same global object (I thought) is visible across translation units (at least that's my expectation). However (mysteriously to me) it looks like the classA c-tor is called more than once. Could anyone elaborate on it, pls?

Comment: `const A ;` is not valid, do you mean `const classA A;` ?

Comment: sorry, let me correct

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted so far to cause the constructor to get called more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The same global object (I thought) is visible across translation units (at least that's my expectation).

No, it's only "visible" in translation units in which it is declared, and it seems to only be declared in one of them.

And in this case the global is declared `const` which means it has internal linkage, so other translation units can't refer to it even if they declare it.

What is visible to all TUs is the function, which returns the global *by reference*, so other TUs can't refer to the object directly, but they can get a reference to it by calling the function.

You're right that the constructor won't be called more than once though. Presumably other code is creating instances of  the same type, or copying the one returned by that function.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming const A is a typo instead of const classA A the code provided should only construct A once. However, since nothing here prevents OTHER usages of classA, it might be constructed in another, unseen part of code.